# indicates cases to be filled in activity

Tags: android

i am programming an application that has information to be enter by the user, i did a

code that oblige him to fill all the cases, if he didn't do it a text signal to the user that

he should fill all, but now i am trying to show the user the only cases that left empty ?

i don't know how to do it ?? thanks for help

HERE is the code for verification :

```
        if (rm_1ts.equals("") ||rm_2ts.equals("")||rm_3ts.equals("")||rm_4ts.equals("")||rm_5ts.equals("")
                          ||rm_6ts.equals("")||rm_7ts.equals("")||rm_8ts.equals("")||rm_9_1ts.equals("")
                          ||rm_9_2ts.equals("")||rm_10ts.equals("")||rm_11_1ts.equals("")||rm_11_2ts.equals("")
                          ||rm_12ts.equals("")|| rm_15ts.equals("")|| a == 0|| b == 0
                          ) {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityUn.this,"fill all the cases",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                  else   { ajouter(v);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is have an `ImageView` next to each area that a user can enter text. You can set them to invisible with `setVisibility()` passing in either `INVISIBLE` to mark that the `ImageView` should be invisible to the user but still take up space on the layout, or `GONE` to mark it as invisible and not take space in the layout. Then when you detect that one of the fields is empty you can just switch the visibility of the `ImageView` next to that layout to `VISIBLE`. As the image in the `ImageView` you could use something like a red arrow pointing to the empty field, or something that indicates that the user should fill out that field. Once the user fills out the field you can mark the `ImageView` as either `INVISIBLE` or `GONE` again to make the image disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make a toast in each one of the fields

```
if(rm_1ts.equals(""){
Toast.makeText();
}
```

and so on. I would suggest though that you use switch statements here, or else the code will be highly difficult to manage and read later on

Comment: thanks for answer, so i should write this code inside the if condition ?? and what do you mean by switch statements ? thanks for responding

Comment: Yea put it in the if condition. And for the switch statement check this link: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=649

Answer (score 2):

Do not do so ugly things :s, there are so many pretty [libraries](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar&ei=xnqiUr2BNseVyQOw5YHIAQ&usg=AFQjCNGtYCubjqVDpwZ5bNSMF_bb00NfpA&sig2=ECyC_XlZkLQppBjukDhDww) available for form validation.

[Check this tuto](http://blog.zasadnyy.org.ua/2013/08/android-form-validation-right-way.html)

Comment: Thats why i made the comment of using switch in my answer.

Comment: @ user2511882 :  now i know what did you say, thanks for idea :)